# How to Merge two Panel data sets on Date and a combination of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two datasets, `df1` &`df2`, that look like this:

`df1`:

| Date | Code | City | State | Population | Cases | Deaths |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-03 | 10001 | Los Angeles | CA | 5000000 | 122 | 12 |
| 2020-03 | 10002 | Sacramento | CA | 5400000 | 120 | 2 |
| 2020-03 | 12223 | Houston | TX | 3500000 | 23 | 11 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-07 | 10001 | Los Angeles | CA | 5000002 | 12220 | 2200 |
| 2021-07 | 10002 | Sacramento | CA | 5444000 | 211 | 22 |
| 2021-07 | 12223 | Houston | TX | 4443300 | 2111 | 330 |

`df2`:

| Date | Code | City | State | Quantity x | Quantity y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01 | 100015 | LOS ANGELES | CA |  | 445 |
| 2019-01 | 100015 | LOS ANGELES | CA | 330 |  |
| 2019-01 | 100023 | SACRAMENTO | CA | 4450 | 566 |
| 2019-01 | 1222393 | HOUSTON | TX | 440 | NA |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-07 | 100015 | LOS ANGELES | CA | 31113 | 3455 |
| 2021-07 | 100023 | SACRAMENTO | CA | 3220 | NA |
| 2021-07 | 1222393 | HOUSTON | TX | NA | 3200 |

As you can see, `df2` starts before `df1`, but they both end on the same dates. Also, `df1` and `df2` both have IDs that share some commonalities but are not equal (in general, `df2` has an extra one or two digits than `df1`).

Also note that there may be multiple entries for the same date on `df2`, but with different quantities.

I want to merge the two, more specifically I want to merge `df1` on `df2`, such that it starts on `2019-01` and ends on `2021-07`. In that case, `Cases` and `Deaths` would be 0 between `2019-01` and `2020-02`.

How can I merge `df1` on `df2` using Date, City, and State (given that some cities have the same name but are in different states) and using the date specifications mentioned above? I would like my combined data frame, `df3`, to look like this:

| Date | Code | City | State | Quantity x | Quantity y | Population | Cases | Deaths |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01 | 10001 | Los Angeles | CA |  | 445 |  | 0 | 0 |
| 2019-01 | 10002 | Sacramento | CA | 4450 | 556 |  | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-03 | 12223 | Houston | TX | 440 | 4440 | 35000000 | 23 | 11 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-07 | 10002 | Sacramento | CA | 3220 | NA | 5444000 | 211 | 22 |

Edit: I was thinking: maybe I can first cut `df1`'s date range and then do the merge. I am not sure about how an outer merge would work with dates that don't necessarily overlap. Perhaps someone has a better idea.

Comment: Your ask isn't clear. It sounds like you perhaps want to do both a merge _and aggregation_ over [dates? cities/dates?] (i.e. "`Cases` and `Deaths` would be 0 between")? Could you 1.) convert your example tables to actual code (i.e. `df1 = pd.DataFrame(...)` and `df2 = ...`) then 2.) write out the desired final `DataFrame`?

Comment: @webelo I added a table that exemplifies what I want. Essentially, I want to combine both of the dataframes. On the dates that `df1` and `df2` do not share, I want `Cases` and `Deaths` to be 0. Hope it clarifies!

Comment: Sorry - I'm still not following: It looks like the `Code` is different for LA `2019-01` relative to `df2` (`10001` v. `100015`)? Is `Code` even relevant here? Also, how are you treating the 2nd visible LA/`2019-01` row? Should the `Quantity x` value of 330 be discarded? Or summed? Or is there a missing panel variable? Posting an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (with a focus on essential elements) would make this answerable.

Comment: @webelo I am not sure I am able to write an MWE with such information. I am also pretty new to pytjon so that would take a lot of time, with that I am sorry for the confusion. The code in this case not relevant for merging because they are different. 

In terms of the 2nd visible LA/2019-01 row, it would be a row in and of it's own. The `Quantity x` value of 330 would be a new row. Sorry for the confusion I hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the `how` keyword argument in [`pd.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=how%20outer) and [`pd.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html?highlight=how%20outer).

Here is a sample:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_json(
    '{"Date":{"0":1583020800000,"1":1583020800000,"2":1583020800000,"3":1625097600000,"4":1625097600000,"5":1625097600000},"City":{"0":"Los Angeles","1":"Sacramento","2":"Houston","3":"Los Angeles","4":"Sacramento","5":"Houston"},"State":{"0":"CA","1":"CA","2":"TX","3":"CA","4":"CA","5":"TX"},"Population":{"0":5000000,"1":5400000,"2":3500000,"3":5000002,"4":5444000,"5":4443300},"Cases":{"0":122,"1":120,"2":23,"3":12220,"4":211,"5":2111},"Deaths":{"0":12,"1":2,"2":11,"3":2200,"4":22,"5":330}}'
)
df2 = pd.read_json(
    '{"Date":{"0":1546300800000,"1":1546300800000,"2":1546300800000,"3":1546300800000,"4":1625097600000,"5":1625097600000,"6":1625097600000},"City":{"0":"LOS ANGELES","1":"LOS ANGELES","2":"SACRAMENTO","3":"HOUSTON","4":"LOS ANGELES","5":"SACRAMENTO","6":"HOUSTON"},"State":{"0":"CA","1":"CA","2":"CA","3":"TX","4":"CA","5":"CA","6":"TX"},"Quantity x":{"0":null,"1":330.0,"2":4450.0,"3":440.0,"4":31113.0,"5":3220.0,"6":null},"Quantity y":{"0":445.0,"1":null,"2":566.0,"3":null,"4":3455.0,"5":null,"6":3200.0}}'
)

print("\ndf1 = \n", df1)
print("\ndf2 = \n", df2)

# Transform df1
df1["City"] = df1["City"].apply(str.upper)  # To merge, need consistent casing
df1 = df1.groupby(["Date", "City", "State"])[
    ["Cases", "Deaths"]
].sum()  # Aggregate cases + deaths just in case...


# Aggregate in df2
df2 = df2.groupby(["Date", "City", "State"])[
    ["Quantity x", "Quantity y"]
].sum()  # implicit skipna=True

print("\ndf1' = \n", df1)
print("\ndf2' = \n", df2)

# MERGE: merging on indices
df3 = df1.join(df2, how="outer")  # key: "how"
df3[["Cases", "Deaths"]] = (
    df3[["Cases", "Deaths"]].fillna(0).astype(int)
)  # inplace: downcasting complaint

df3.reset_index(
    inplace=True
)  # Will cause ["Date", "City", "State"] to be ordinary columns, not indices.

print("\ndf3 = \n", df3)
```

...the output is:

```
df1 = 
         Date         City State  Population  Cases  Deaths
0 2020-03-01  Los Angeles    CA     5000000    122      12
1 2020-03-01   Sacramento    CA     5400000    120       2
2 2020-03-01      Houston    TX     3500000     23      11
3 2021-07-01  Los Angeles    CA     5000002  12220    2200
4 2021-07-01   Sacramento    CA     5444000    211      22
5 2021-07-01      Houston    TX     4443300   2111     330

df2 = 
         Date         City State  Quantity x  Quantity y
0 2019-01-01  LOS ANGELES    CA         NaN       445.0
1 2019-01-01  LOS ANGELES    CA       330.0         NaN
2 2019-01-01   SACRAMENTO    CA      4450.0       566.0
3 2019-01-01      HOUSTON    TX       440.0         NaN
4 2021-07-01  LOS ANGELES    CA     31113.0      3455.0
5 2021-07-01   SACRAMENTO    CA      3220.0         NaN
6 2021-07-01      HOUSTON    TX         NaN      3200.0

df1' = 
                               Cases  Deaths
Date       City        State               
2020-03-01 HOUSTON     TX        23      11
           LOS ANGELES CA       122      12
           SACRAMENTO  CA       120       2
2021-07-01 HOUSTON     TX      2111     330
           LOS ANGELES CA     12220    2200
           SACRAMENTO  CA       211      22

df2' = 
                               Quantity x  Quantity y
Date       City        State                        
2019-01-01 HOUSTON     TX          440.0         0.0
           LOS ANGELES CA          330.0       445.0
           SACRAMENTO  CA         4450.0       566.0
2021-07-01 HOUSTON     TX            0.0      3200.0
           LOS ANGELES CA        31113.0      3455.0
           SACRAMENTO  CA         3220.0         0.0

df3 = 
         Date         City State  Cases  Deaths  Quantity x  Quantity y
0 2019-01-01      HOUSTON    TX      0       0       440.0         0.0
1 2019-01-01  LOS ANGELES    CA      0       0       330.0       445.0
2 2019-01-01   SACRAMENTO    CA      0       0      4450.0       566.0
3 2020-03-01      HOUSTON    TX     23      11         NaN         NaN
4 2020-03-01  LOS ANGELES    CA    122      12         NaN         NaN
5 2020-03-01   SACRAMENTO    CA    120       2         NaN         NaN
6 2021-07-01      HOUSTON    TX   2111     330         0.0      3200.0
7 2021-07-01  LOS ANGELES    CA  12220    2200     31113.0      3455.0
8 2021-07-01   SACRAMENTO    CA    211      22      3220.0         0.0
```

A few other points:

- `City` casing needs to be consistent at join/merge time.
- You could also do: `df1.merge(df2, ..., left_index=True, right_index=True)` instead of `df1.join`. You could also reset the indices via `df1.reset_index(inplace=True)`, etc. after the groupby-sum line(s) then use `.merge(..., on=...)` (but the indices are convenient).
- The final values of `Quantity {x,y}` are floats because `NaN`s are present. (See next point.)
- I would be deliberate about your treatment of `NaN`s v. auto-filled 0s. In the case of `Cases`/`Deaths` it sounds like you had no data *BUT* you were making the assumption that - in the absence of `Cases`/`Deaths` data - the values are `0`. For the `Quantity {x,y}` variables, no such assumption seemed to be warranted.